# Broadcasting to all clients with Deno websocket

Tags: javascript, sockets, websocket, react-context, deno

I want to add notifications to an application I've developed.

Unfortunately, Deno has removed the ws package.(https://deno.land/std@0.110.0/ws/mod.ts)

That's why I'm using the websocket inside the denon itself. Since it doesn't have many functions, I have to add some things myself.
For example, sending all messages to open clients.

What I want to do is when the pdf is created, a (data, message) comes from the socket and update the notifications on the page according to the incoming data.

I keep all open clients in a Map. and when the pdf is created, I return this Map and send it to all sockets (data, message).

However, this works for one time.

***server conf...***

```
    import {
        path,
        paths,
        ctid,
    } from "../deps.ts";
    
    const users = new Map();
    const sockets = new Map()
    const userArr = [];
    
    export const startNotif = (socket,req) => {
        const claims = req.get("claims");
        const org = req.get("org");
        claims.org = org;
    
        console.log("connected")
        users.set(claims.sub, {"username":claims.sub,"socket":socket})
    
        users.forEach((user)=>{
        if(userArr.length === 0){
            userArr.push(user)
        }
        else if(userArr.every((w)=> w.username !== user.username) )
            userArr.push(user)
        })
        
        sockets.set(org, userArr)
    
        function broadcastMessage(message) {
        sockets.get(org).map((u)=>{
            console.log(u.socket.readyState)
            u.socket.send(message)
        })
    }
    
        if (socket.readyState === 3) {
        sockets.delete(uid)
        return
        }
    
        const init = (msg) => {
        socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
            status: "creating",
            })
        );
        };
    
        const ondata = async (msg) => {
        const upfilepath = path.join(paths.work, `CT_${msg.sid}_report.pdf`);
        try {
            const s=await Deno.readTextFile(upfilepath);
            if(s){
            socket.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                status: "end",
                })
            );
            } else {
            socket.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                status: "creating",
                })
            );
            }
        } catch(e) {
            if(e instanceof Deno.errors.NotFound)
            console.error('file does not exists');
        }
        
        };
    
    
        const end = () => {
        try {
            const endTime = Date.now()
            const msg = "Your PDF has been created"
            const id = ctid(12) // random id create
            broadcastMessage(
            JSON.stringify({
                id: id,
                date: endTime,
                status: "done",
                message: msg,
                read: 'negative',
                action: 'pdf'
            })
            );
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(400, "Cannot send.", e);
        }
        }
    
        socket.onmessage = async (e) => {
        const cmd = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if(cmd.bid === 'start'){
            await init(cmd)
        }
        if(!cmd.bid && cmd.sid){
            await ondata(cmd)
        }
        if(cmd.bid === 'end'){
            await end();
        }
        }
    
        socket.onerror = (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        };
    }
```

***client conf...***

```
export const webSocketHandler = (request) =>
new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let url;
    if (!process.env.NODE_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        url = `http://localhost:8080/api/notifications/ws`.replace('http', 'ws');
    } else {
        url = `${window.location.origin}/api/notifications/ws`.replace('http', 'ws');
    }
    const token = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('token'));
    const orgname = localStorage.getItem('orgname');
    const protocol = `${token}_org_${orgname}`;

    const socket = new WebSocket(url, protocol);
    const response = Object.create({});

    socket.onopen = function () {
        socket.send(
            JSON.stringify({
                bid: 'start',
            })
        );
    };

    socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        response.data = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (response.data.status === 'creating') {
            socket.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    sid: request.sid,
                })
            );
        } else if (response.data.status === 'end') {
            socket.send(
                JSON.stringify({
                    bid: 'end',
                })
            );
        } else if (response.data.status === 'done') {
            try {
                res(response);
            } catch (err) {
                rej(err);
            }
        }
    };

    socket.onclose = function (event) {
        response.state = event.returnValue;
    };

    socket.onerror = function (error) {
        rej(error);
    };
});
```

***onclick function of button I use in component...***

```
const donwloadReport = async (type) => {
const query = `?sid=${sid}&reportType=${type}`;
const fileName = `CT_${sid}_report.${type}`;
try {
    type === 'pdf' && setLoading(true);
    const response = await getScanReportAction(query);
    const request = {
        sid,
    };
    webSocketHandler(request)
        .then((data) => {
            console.log(data);
            dispatch({
                type: 'update',
                data: {
                    id: data.data.id,
                    date: data.data.date,
                    message: data.data.message,
                    action: data.data.action,
                    read: data.data.read,
                },
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    if (type === 'html') {
        downloadText(response.data, fileName);
    } else {
        const blobUrl = await readStream(response.data);
        setLoading(false);
        downloadURL(blobUrl, fileName);
    }
} catch (err) {
    displayMessage(err.message);
}
};
```

Everything works perfectly the first time. When I press the download button for the pdf, the socket works, then a data is returned and I update the notification count with the context I applied according to this data.

Later I realized that this works in a single tab. When I open a new client in the side tab, my notification count does not increase. For this, I wanted to keep all sockets in Map and return them all and send a message to each socket separately. But in this case, when I press the download button for the second time, no data comes from the socket.

Actually, I think that I should do the socket initialization process on the client in the context. When you do this, it starts the socket 2 times in a meaningless way.

In summary, consider an application with organizations and users belonging to those organizations. If the clients of A, B, C users belonging to X organization are open at the same time and user A pressed a pdf download button, I want A, B, C users to be notified when the pdf is downloaded.

I would be very grateful if someone could show me a way around this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the BroadcastChannel API? Maybe that could solve your issue. See for example:

- Deno specific: https://medium.com/deno-the-complete-reference/broadcast-channel-in-deno-f76a0b8893f5
- Web/Browser API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API